# I defined a static IP in the docker compose file but I can only access it on 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm creating a docker-compose file to be able to access different containers over an IP on my machine. My Docker compose file is the following:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  apache-php8:
    build: ./apache-php8
    volumes:
     - ../webphp8:/var/www/html/web
    ports:
     - 80:80    
    networks:
      web_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.4

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7    
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    networks:
      web_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.3

networks:
  web_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.100.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.100.1
```

I'd expect being able to acces the code on the machine on the 192.168.100.4, as that is the IP that I defined for the server, however, I only access to it in the 0.0.0.0 IP. I'm in an Ubuntu host machine, if that matters.

Do you know why is that, and what I have to do to change it to access the server on 192.168.100.4?

**Answer to "Why are you doing it?":** I want to be able to develop with two different versions of PHP in the same machine, and access them with two different urls: http://app1.webserver.es and http://app2.webserver.es. I also want a connection to the database that is accessible locally and for the webservers.

Comment: I would guess that your apache server in `apache-php8` is only listening on localhost, and therefore you can only connect to it through the mapped 80  port.

Comment: I guess so, but as I defined the IP as 192.168.100.4, shouldn't it be accessible on it?

Comment: No, when an application starts listening for incoming connections it specifies not only on which port but also for which IP it wasn't to listen. Some applications by default only listen to localhost. With `ipv4_address: 192.168.100.4` you do not map `192.186.100.4` to localhost of the docker container, instead, you create an additional network interface with the IP `192.186.100.4`. And if you didn't configure the server to listen either on all network interfaces or on `192.186.100.4` specifically it doesn't do that.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do. Do you want to access the container only on the host machine where the container is running or in your whole network?

Comment: I want to have several PHP servers at the same time on my network, each of them in different IPs so I can address them in my /etc/hosts. I was able to do that in the past, but it's not working anymore. For example, I want to set 192.168.100.4 for domain1, and 192.168.100.8 for domain2, each of them will have different PHP versions

Comment: I understand that part. But do you only want to access `192.168.100.4`/`192.168.100.8` only on your docker host or also from other physical machines in the network?

Comment: Hi t.niese, only in my host

Comment: At the end, I finished using something different: Two PHP webservers with a Mysql on the same network, with Nginx managing all. I left the code on https://github.com/Chocofede/lamps-nginx/tree/master if you want to check it. It allows accessing with a local domain to any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem has been changing the approach: instead of using IPs that expose the network, go for a Nginx reverse proxy that manages the incoming traffic from the host to the containers.

I published the code on this repository: https://github.com/Chocofede/lamps-nginx/tree/master

The key parts are:

- Configure the docker-compose.yml to put all containers on the same network
- Configure the Nginx to do the reverse proxy: It sends the address from the host to the containers and allows showing them without having to change ports.
- Configure the web servers to serve the address.
- Set the local address in the hosts.

### All containers in the same network: the docker-compose file

In the `docker-compose.yml`, let's set the configuration to put all the servers are in the same network:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - my_network <<<< Same Network
    depends_on:
      - web_server1
      - web_server2
      - mysql_server

  web_server1:
    [...]
    networks:
      - my_network <<<< Same Network
    depends_on:
      - mysql_server

  web_server2:
    [...]
    networks:
      - my_network <<<< Same Network
    depends_on:
      - mysql_server

  mysql_server:
    [...]
    networks:
      - my_network <<<< Same Network
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  my_network: <<<< Network name
    driver: bridge
```

### Reverse proxy to have all in the same 80 port: Nginx configuration

The trickiest part of this solution was that I wanted all the servers on the 80 port, and being able to access them from a local address. To do so, we have to configure the `nginx.conf` file to send the traffic from the hosts to the containers.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
      [...]

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app1.webserver.es; <<<< Address for webserver 1

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web_server1;
            [...]
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app2.webserver.es; <<<< Address for Webser 2

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web_server2;
            [...]
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysql.webserver.es; <<<< Address for MySql

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://mysql_server;
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

That will let the servers listening in their 80 ports without interfering with the 80 port of the host.

### Configure the web servers to serve the address

In both web servers, I had to configure the server name to allow access:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app1.webserver.es <<<< The local name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Set the local address in the host

And last, but not least, adding to `/etc/hosts` (I'm in Ubuntu) file the addresses to access them locally:

```
127.0.0.1 app1.webserver.es
127.0.0.1 app2.webserver.es
127.0.0.1 mysql.webserver.es
```

With that, when launching the server, it gives you a nice

[image: You can see a webserver showing a message that its connection to the database worked]

Thanks to all the people that helped me figuring out the answer.

Comment: Its good to see you answered your own question.  You also could have used a macvlan or ipvlan network with addresses defined as a small slice of your host network.  you may still have needed to add host entries if you cared to use dns, but all of your containers on that network would have distinct addresses on your host network.  I use this for some containers that need to be able to multicast on my host network.

Answer (score 1):

When you define ports in a docker compose file like:

```yaml
ports:
 - 80:80
```

It binds the container's port 80 to the host's port 80 on all available interfaces, which typically includes `127.0.0.1` (localhost) and `0.0.0.0` (all IP addresses on the local machine).

That is why you are able to access your services via `0.0.0.0` or `localhost`.

However, docker does not bind container IPs to the host system directly. IP addresses assigned within a docker compose file via `ipv4_adresses` are internal. to the docker bridge network (`web_net` in this case) and not exposed to the host network interface directly.

If you really want to access the container using `192.168.100.4` from your host machine, there are a few things you can do:

1. **Use the host network**: This is generally a bad idea because it bypasses the managed docker network, but it would allow you to bind your services directly yo the host's network
2. **Custom Host Entry**: You could add an entry to the host's `/etc/hosts` file that maps `192.168.100.4` back to `localhost`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, I tried modifying my hosts file to link it. Interesting enough, the entry "192.168.100.4 localhost" shows the web, BUT "192.168.100.4 mydomain.com" it doesn't. How can I achieve that a domain in my machine will go to 192.168.100.4?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know why is that, and what I have to do to change it to access the server on 192.168.100.4?

Containers within Docker have their own virtual network within your host machine (i.e., the physical laptop or desktop you are using).  Within this virtual network, the containers (`mysql` and `apache-php8`) talk to each other using the IP addresses you defined (the `192.168.100.0/24` subnet).  Therefore the `mysql` container (and any other container you create in the cluster) will reach `apache-php8` via either the IP address (`192.168.100.4`) or the `apache-php8` hostname.  These `192.168.100.#` IP addresses are not available to you from the host machine, but must be exposed.

Exposing your `apache-php8` container's ports are accomplished as you have already done (`ports: - 80:80`), and that allows you to access `apache-php8` port 80 via your laptop's `localhost` hostname or `127.0.0.1` loopback IP address.  If you wish to access `apache-php8` via the `192.168.100.4` IP address, you would need to first get into a container on that virtual network and then connect to `192.168.100.4` as needed (though there are not many human/practical uses for that -- it's generally so that containers/services can talk to each other in the network)

On a side note, I have seen instances where a web service (or some other service) was started up in a container, but only listening on `127.0.0.1` or the container IP address.  If this is the case, only the container itself (`127.0.0.1`) or other containers with access to the virtual network (`192.168.100.*`) could talk to that service.  The only way to make it available to the host machine is by starting the application/service (Apache, MySQL, etc.) with listen on `'*'` or `0.0.0.0`, which allows incoming traffic to all of that container's network addresses.

Comment: It sounds quite interesting what you mention. So, if I wanted to access 192.168.100.4, I have to expose that IP to my host machine, isn't it? I want to do that, so I can link a domain in my host going to that address, and thus I can after that having several machines at the same time in my host machine

Comment: I guess that the last part that you mention would be doing the following: https://serverfault.com/questions/226231/how-to-make-apache-listen-on-a-particular-ip, right?

Comment: I think it would require more than exposing an IP or linking a domain -- I think you would need to set up a router on your laptop (or wherever the Ubuntu host is running on), and set up routing rules to direct incoming traffic to the Docker container.  After that, you would need to set up your DNS outside the Ubuntu instance (i.e., your server room network) to route traffic for the specific hostname to the Ubuntu instance, so that it can get routed to the Docker container -- that's a bit too complicated, and you might be better off using a container service like AWS ECS/Fargate or Lambda

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it helped me to figure out a solution: Nginx with all the servers together. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

In Docker, when you specify ports in the docker-compose.yml file (like `80:80` for the `apache-php8` service), it binds the container's port to a port on the host machine. This binding is usually to the host's IP address, which is often represented as `0.0.0.0`, meaning it's accessible on all network interfaces of the host. This is why you're able to access your service via the host's IP or localhost, but not directly via the container's internal IP (like `192.168.100.4`).

To access your containers using the internal IPs defined in your Docker network (`192.168.100.x`), you need to interact within the Docker network context. This is typically done from within another container on the same network. However, accessing these internal IPs directly from the host machine (Ubuntu in your case) is not straightforward because this network is isolated and managed by Docker.

If you want to access your services using specific IPs from your host machine, you have a few options:

- Use the host network driver instead of a bridge network, but this removes the network isolation provided by Docker.
- Access the Docker network namespace using advanced networking commands in Linux. This approach is complex and generally not recommended for typical use cases.
- Configure routing on your Ubuntu host to direct traffic to the `192.168.100.0/24` subnet through the Docker bridge network. This involves advanced network configuration and may not be suitable for all environments.
- Implement a service discovery mechanism or use Docker's built-in service discovery features by referring to services by their names (e.g., `apache-php8`) within the Docker network.